# Force GET variable (url) to not be encoded

Tags: php, url, encode

I've been coding in PHP for a while, and this is the first time I came across this issue.
My goal is to pass a GET variable (a url) without encoding or decoding it. Which means that "%2F" will not turn to "/" and the opposite. The reason for that is that I'm passing this variable to a 3rd party website and the vairable must stay exactly the way it is.

Right now what's happening is that this url (passed as a GET variable):`http://example.com/something%2Felse` turns into `http://example.com/something/else`.

How can I prevent php from encoding what's passed in GET?

Comment: Please provide a complete demonstration of what you are doing here and how "PHP is encoding/decoding it".

Comment: you cant have a space in a url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache denies all URLs with %2F in the path part, for security reasons: scripts can't normally (ie. without rewriting) tell the difference between %2F and / due to the PATH_INFO environment variable being automatically URL-decoded (which is stupid, but a long-standing part of the CGI specification so there's nothing can be done about it).

You can turn this feature off using the AllowEncodedSlashes directive, but note that other web servers will still disallow it (with no option to turn that off), and that other characters may also be taboo (eg. %5C), and that %00 in particular will always be blocked by both Apache and IIS. So if your application relied on being able to have %2F or other characters in a path part you'd be limiting your compatibility/deployment options.

I am using urlencode() while preparing the search URL

You should use rawurlencode(), not urlencode() for escaping path parts. urlencode() is misnamed, it is actually for application/x-www-form-urlencoded data such as in the query string or the body of a POST request, and not for other parts of the URL.

The difference is that + doesn't mean space in path parts. rawurlencode() will correctly produce %20 instead, which will work both in form-encoded data and other parts of the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Eventually I found it easier to find the slash prior to passing it to the next page and replacing it with a temporeraly variable (and the opposite action just before I'm passing the url to the 3rd party website)

Answer (score 0):

Hex base16 encoding it is part of the HTTP protocol you cant prevent it else it would break the actual HTTP socket request to the server.

Use:

- [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/urlencode) to encode
- [urldecode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode

Please show an actual example of how you are sending the url to the 3rd party.

As it should read `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fsomething%2Felse` not just the odd `%2F` like in your example.